# Aspose.Cells - get the rangename for a cell

Tags: vb.net, aspose-cells

I'm using aspose.cells in a .NET application.  Let's say I have an excel workbook with three sheets named Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3.  In Sheet1, cell A1 has been named "Apple" with global scope.  In worksheets Sheet2 and Sheet3, cell A1 is named "Banana" (so it is not global.)

So in my VB.NET code I have a Cell. It seems like the Aspose name is just the letter-number.
What I want is if I'm referencing the cell A1, a function that returns "Apple" if that cell is in SHeet1, and "Banana" if that cell is in Sheet2 or Sheet3.

It seems like this should be straightforward, but the only solution I've seen involves creating helper functions that work with the entire names collection?

Answer (score 0):

To get specific worksheet scoped named range, you need to get it with respect to its worksheet. For global (Workbook) named range, you can directly access it via its name. See the sample code for your reference:

e.g.

**Sample code:**

```vb
'Open the Excel file
Dim workbook As Workbook = New Workbook("g:\test2\Book1.xlsx")
'Get the worksheet collection
Dim worksheets As WorksheetCollection = workbook.Worksheets

'Getting the specified global named range
Dim namedRange As Range = worksheets.GetRangeByName("Apple")
Console.WriteLine("Named Range : " & namedRange.RefersTo)

'Getting the specified local named range
Dim namedRange2 As Range = worksheets.GetRangeByName("Sheet2!Banana")
Console.WriteLine("Named Range : " & namedRange2.RefersTo)

'Getting the specified local named range
Dim namedRange3 As Range = worksheets.GetRangeByName("Sheet3!Banana")
Console.WriteLine("Named Range : " & namedRange3.RefersTo)

....
```

Hope, this helps a bit.

You may also post your queries in the dedicated [forum](https://forum.aspose.com/c/cells/9).

PS. I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: Hi  Amjad - greatly appreciate the response.  However, was looking for the inverse of these.  Something like, GetNameByRange?  So that for an argument Sheet2!A1, the function return would be "Banana" (provided the single cell A1 was named "Banana")  Thanks!

Comment: You can browse through named ranges and check if your argument matches with named range's RefersTo value, so you could get the relevant rangename.